# Font download from png generator

Tags: fonts

I am trying to understand how this webpage works. Here is the url:

https://www.hypefortype.com/foundries/thinkdust/nanami-extended-39.html

I am trying to understand the image generation of the fonts here. I go to type tester, I type in my text, and I see that everytime I type a new letter, a request gets sent to a preview file, here in the left column:

[image]

Based on this, I would like to find the path to the font. At the very bottom of the right column, I can see that the path to the font used to generated the preview image is supposedly: **/n/a/nanami-extended-medoblq.otf**

Except, when I type these urls in my url bar, none of them work:

https://www.hypefortype.com/generator/n/a/nanami-extended-medoblq.otf
https://www.hypefortype.com/n/a/nanami-extended-medoblq.otf

What am I missing here? Shouldn't I be able to access the font from this url? Is the font stored on another server?

Comment: Simple question: what makes you think this happens client side at all?

Comment: That is why I am asking the question, because I am not sure about this. I am just wondering where the font is hosted and how it is being accessed by the website.

Comment: You're seeing how it's being accessed in the screenshot you're showing: you type things, javascript calls the server's `/preview` URL with your text, and the server sends an image back that shows what that looks like. Pretty cut and dry?

Comment: Correct, and based on that conclusion, what is the direct accessible path to the .otf font file?

Comment: That logic doesn't follow. If something happens on the server rather than on the client, the first assumption is instead that this is done to ensure you *don't* have access. Especially when it comes to expensive, heavily licensed data, the whole reason to have the server render previews is to make sure you can't illegally download the font anyway just by doing a bit of poking around in dev tools (this font family costs 100 pound sterling. You really think they'd stay in business if they gave you access to the whole font before you payed for it?)